# getenv in C++ returns wrong values

Tags: c++, environment-variables, getenv

I would like to write my program in 2 different paths. So, I proceeded like that :

```
std::string path1 = strcat(std::getenv("APPDATA"),"\\myprog.exe") ;
std::string path2 = strcat(std::getenv("APPDATA"),"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\myprog.exe") ;
```

When I print, I get :

```
C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\myprog.exe
C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\myprog.exe\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\myprog.exe
```

instead of :

```
C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\myprog.exe
C:\Users\thispc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\myprog.exe
```

**Solution by Dietmar Kühl :**

```
std::string path1 = std::getenv("APPDATA") + std::string("\\myprog.exe");
```

**Explanation by Oliver Charlesworth :**
`strcat()` changes the 1st variable

Comment: You clearly change the result of the first call to `std::getenv()` (which, I think, is actually illegal). Did you mean to write something like `std::string path1 = std::getenv("APPDATA") + std::string("\\myprog.exe");`?

Comment: `strcat` modifies the string pointed to by its first argument.  That's legal in general, but not in this particular case - you don't know how much storage was allocated for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that `std::getenv("APPDATA")` gives you a pointer to a already written string somewhere in memory, that means the pointer returned by this function will always be the same.

Thus when you do `strcat(std::getenv("APPDATA"),"\\myprog.exe")` you basically concatenate that stored string in memory with `"\\myprog.exe"`. So when you make a second call of `std::getenv("APPDATA")` you will get the concatenated string.

To solve this problem you should copy the string at `std::getenv("APPDATA")`